# iOS 8 UIView not getting updated issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uitextfield

I have a UIView with a `UITextField` placed at the bottom of the screen which I'd like to move up when a keyboard appears.
I have added `keyboardFrameDidChange` observer for getting notified whenever a keyboard appears/disappears. Here is the method :

```
-(void)keyboardFrameDidChange:(NSNotification*)notification{

NSDictionary* info = [notification userInfo];

CGRect kKeyBoardFrame = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];

[bottomView layoutIfNeeded];

[UIView animateWithDuration:[notification.userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue] delay:0 options:[[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] integerValue] animations:^{

    [bottomView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, kKeyBoardFrame.origin.y - bottomView.frame.size.height, 320, bottomView.frame.size.height)];

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    [bottomView layoutIfNeeded];

    NSLog(@"frame ** %f",self.bottomView.frame.origin.y);
}];
}
```

Here the `frame of bottomView` is changing but nothing happens in the UI. The `bottomView` just remains at the bottom. What might be the reason?

Comment: Have you checked to see if bottomView is nil?

Comment: @rdelmar Yes. And the origin of bottonView is getting updated correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like an auto layout problem. If auto layout is on, then you should change the view's position by adjusting its constraints, not setting frames. Make an IBOutlet to the constraint between the text field and the bottom of superview (bottomCon in my example), and adjust it.

```
-(void)keyboardFrameDidChange:(NSNotification*)notification{

    NSDictionary* info = [notification userInfo];

    CGRect kKeyBoardFrame = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];

    [_bottomView layoutIfNeeded];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:[notification.userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue] delay:0 options:[[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] integerValue] animations:^{

        self.bottomCon.constant = kKeyBoardFrame.origin.y;
        [_bottomView layoutIfNeeded];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        NSLog(@"frame ** %f",self.bottomView.frame.origin.y);
    }];
}
```

Comment: How did I miss that! You are simple awesome . thanks a lot :)